# How to sign transaction using web3.js via metamask

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask, signature

I'm trying to make a signed transaction in browser with web3 injected from metamask and send the transaction to my backend-server and then submit it to blockchain.

However, it's hard to find how I can just sign transaction(not sending it) and send it to my backend server.

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you share more why you want to do so? Generally, once signed you cannot change it anyway.

Comment: @TurboPanumarch Probably he wants to pay the gas fees for the user

Comment: Any solution ? I want to do same thing over android mobile wallet

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the below for signing data from metamask,

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask
https://github.com/danfinlay/js-eth-personal-sign-examples

Comment: Thanks but I'v already read it and it's about signing data not transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to sign transactions in the browser and send them to your backend server.

The web3.js library provides a method called `eth_signTransaction` which will allow you to sign the transaction and generate a signature.

You can then send the signed transaction to your backend server which can submit it to the blockchain.

Comment: Unfortunately, Metamask does not support `eth_signTransaction`.
It was previously suggested here: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2506, and here they explained why they didn't implement it: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3475